# contentY on nested ListView

Tags: qt, qml

My current implementation uses a ListView that contains a nested ListView as delegate. So, each children is a ListView.

I need to add a lateral label to each children ListView indicating its category. This label must be visible as long as any item of the child list view is still visible. So I need to know the proportional part of ListView visible.

My first idea was to use contentY, which indicates the Y coordinate. The problem is that contentY for the children ListViews is always 0.

How can I get the Y coordinate being shown for each children ListView? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

ListView items not loaded while not on display. So just add label as `header` property for example.